# Container Docker não inicia

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, docker

Sou iniciante em Docker e estou tentando criar um ambiente de desenvolvimento com ngix mysql e php utilizando o Laradock, tenho em minha maquina o Docker instalado, tentei seguir os passos da documentação [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://laradock.io/) porém quando tento subir os container utilizando o comando "docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpmyadmin redis workspace " recebo um log diferente do que é apresentado nos exemplos que vi:

Log do terminal

```
$ docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpmyadmin redis workspace 
Building workspace
Step 1/183 : ARG LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION
Step 2/183 : FROM laradock/workspace:2.2-${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}
 ---> 95b8f4b0dbc9
Step 3/183 : LABEL maintainer="Mahmoud Zalt <mahmoud@zalt.me>"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bd28fe17d1c9
Step 4/183 : ARG LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 30fd93a19c48
Step 5/183 : ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 737caf801742
Step 6/183 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 626f73ab3d1c
Step 7/183 : ARG PUID=1000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d3fec7240145
Step 8/183 : ENV PUID ${PUID}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9314d89dfcf8
Step 9/183 : ARG PGID=1000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 39081249d59f
Step 10/183 : ENV PGID ${PGID}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9ba2d4c7c89f
Step 11/183 : RUN apt-get update -yqq &&     pecl channel-update pecl.php.net &&     groupadd -g ${PGID} laradock &&     useradd -u ${PUID} -g laradock -m laradock -G docker_env &&     usermod -p "*" laradock
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c94fa0da80bc
Step 12/183 : ARG TZ=UTC
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f34681a5e705
Step 13/183 : ENV TZ ${TZ}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f54ef2b9a6d1
Step 14/183 : RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 04bd2acd3a00
Step 15/183 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3cfa7fbae478
Step 16/183 : COPY ./aliases.sh /root/aliases.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b66f7ff3271f
Step 17/183 : COPY ./aliases.sh /home/laradock/aliases.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5f1e4fd86383
Step 18/183 : RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /root/aliases.sh &&     sed -i 's/\r//' /home/laradock/aliases.sh &&     chown laradock:laradock /home/laradock/aliases.sh &&    echo "" >> ~/.bashrc &&     echo "# Load Custom Aliases" >> ~/.bashrc &&    echo "source ~/aliases.sh" >> ~/.bashrc &&     echo "" >> ~/.bashrc
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 04607c0e301f
Step 19/183 : USER laradock
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4836a3fe5980
Step 20/183 : RUN echo "" >> ~/.bashrc &&     echo "# Load Custom Aliases" >> ~/.bashrc &&     echo "source ~/aliases.sh" >> ~/.bashrc &&       echo "" >> ~/.bashrc
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d5bac8243790
Step 21/183 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8702cb102c7a
Step 22/183 : COPY ./composer.json /home/laradock/.composer/composer.json
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 14f2b4e3d978
Step 23/183 : RUN chown -R laradock:laradock /home/laradock/.composer
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a77491571152
Step 24/183 : USER laradock
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 713c4df0be97
Step 25/183 : ARG COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> acf3dd67f0a4
Step 26/183 : ENV COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL ${COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a0bf9a16f6e2
Step 27/183 : RUN if [ ${COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL} = true ]; then     composer global install ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 33f0e46cde33
Step 28/183 : ARG COMPOSER_REPO_PACKAGIST
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 387505d1211b
Step 29/183 : ENV COMPOSER_REPO_PACKAGIST ${COMPOSER_REPO_PACKAGIST}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c6d3e07da7f1
Step 30/183 : RUN if [ ${COMPOSER_REPO_PACKAGIST} ]; then     composer config -g repo.packagist composer ${COMPOSER_REPO_PACKAGIST} ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e871b995cb60
Step 31/183 : RUN echo "" >> ~/.bashrc &&     echo 'export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 862523d60322
Step 32/183 : USER laradock
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e4c0250f5f14
Step 33/183 : RUN echo "" >> ~/.bashrc &&     echo 'export PATH="/var/www/vendor/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b044de479b94
Step 34/183 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 01fb7765e482
Step 35/183 : COPY ./crontab /etc/cron.d
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b05a636166c4
Step 36/183 : RUN chmod -R 644 /etc/cron.d
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a8d441e06229
Step 37/183 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8fe3eebe09d4
Step 38/183 : ARG INSTALL_DRUSH=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0f86d1271ca9
Step 39/183 : ARG DRUSH_VERSION
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 68e3c5a17288
Step 40/183 : ENV DRUSH_VERSION ${DRUSH_VERSION}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f86b4d91583d
Step 41/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_DRUSH} = true ]; then     apt-get -y install mysql-client &&     curl -fsSL -o /usr/local/bin/drush https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/${DRUSH_VERSION}/drush.phar | bash &&     chmod +x /usr/local/bin/drush &&     drush core-status ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c544b19dac6d
Step 42/183 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9b4daa396020
Step 43/183 : ARG INSTALL_SSH2=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 058b6e3f8978
Step 44/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_SSH2} = true ]; then   apt-get -y install libssh2-1-dev php${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}-ssh2 ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ee95f83e829b
Step 45/183 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 14b3e459a8dd
Step 46/183 : ARG INSTALL_GMP=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ad9f53fc720f
Step 47/183 : ARG PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4da6a54e4b8c
Step 48/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_GMP} = true ]; then   apt-get -y install php${PHP_VERSION}-gmp ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a2fd5a050a68
Step 49/183 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 880e15dbf53e
Step 50/183 : ARG INSTALL_SOAP=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bcb2731ad0ec
Step 51/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_SOAP} = true ]; then   apt-get -y install libxml2-dev php${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}-soap ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0e1238ef6a4d
Step 52/183 : ARG INSTALL_LDAP=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 54be382c7161
Step 53/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_LDAP} = true ]; then     apt-get install -y libldap2-dev &&     apt-get install -y php${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}-ldap ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b26ffef7c756
Step 54/183 : ARG INSTALL_IMAP=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e39d7df6c149
Step 55/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_IMAP} = true ]; then     apt-get install -y php${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}-imap ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ac0d69c6e256
Step 56/183 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 94598a39fb42
Step 57/183 : ARG INSTALL_SUBVERSION=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 096a8bf451ce
Step 58/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_SUBVERSION} = true ]; then     apt-get install-y subversion ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6191d8d17d10
Step 59/183 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ff6cdbede4d1
Step 60/183 : ARG INSTALL_XDEBUG=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ff2c6762a88c
Step 61/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_XDEBUG} = true ]; then     apt-get install -y php${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}-xdebug &&     sed -i 's/^;//g' /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini &&     echo "alias phpunit='php -dzend_extension=xdebug.so /var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit'" >> ~/.bashrc ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> daa042bb781e
Step 62/183 : COPY ./xdebug.ini /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ede49a403e03
Step 63/183 : RUN sed -i "s/xdebug.remote_autostart=0/xdebug.remote_autostart=1/" /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini &&     sed -i "s/xdebug.remote_enable=0/xdebug.remote_enable=1/" /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini &&     sed -i "s/xdebug.cli_color=0/xdebug.cli_color=1/" /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 25d49155131f
Step 64/183 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a77f345c7461
Step 65/183 : ARG INSTALL_PHPDBG=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 31df86ef73a2
Step 66/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_PHPDBG} = true ]; then     apt-get install -y --force-yes php${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}-phpdbg ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b37949507c4c
Step 67/183 : ARG INSTALL_BLACKFIRE=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e4c79237522b
Step 68/183 : ARG BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a6bbe73148c5
Step 69/183 : ENV BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID ${BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c4bfa96d1817
Step 70/183 : ARG BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ef8991f0888b
Step 71/183 : ENV BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN ${BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 720abbed7091
Step 72/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_XDEBUG} = false -a ${INSTALL_BLACKFIRE} = true]; then     curl -L https://packagecloud.io/gpg.key | apt-key add - &&     echo"deb http://packages.blackfire.io/debian any main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/blackfire.list &&     apt-get update -yqq &&     apt-get install blackfire-agent ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f37c4f924239
Step 73/183 : ARG INSTALL_WORKSPACE_SSH=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 37677a144a20
Step 74/183 : COPY insecure_id_rsa /tmp/id_rsa
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4074a723e9e6
Step 75/183 : COPY insecure_id_rsa.pub /tmp/id_rsa.pub
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2f4e98f81e82
Step 76/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_WORKSPACE_SSH} = true ]; then     rm -f /etc/service/sshd/down &&     cat /tmp/id_rsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys        && cat /tmp/id_rsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub         && cat /tmp/id_rsa >> /root/.ssh/id_rsa         && rm -f /tmp/id_rsa*         && chmod 644 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub     && chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa     && cp -rf /root/.ssh /home/laradock     && chown -R laradock:laradock /home/laradock/.ssh ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 887760651950
Step 77/183 : ARG INSTALL_MONGO=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> de0d315ab9cb
Step 78/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_MONGO} = true ]; then     if [ $(php -r "echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION;") = "5" ]; then       pecl install mongo &&       echo "extension=mongo.so" >> /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/mods-available/mongo.ini &&      ln -s /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/mods-available/mongo.ini /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/cli/conf.d/30-mongo.ini     ;fi &&     pecl install mongodb &&     echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/mods-available/mongodb.ini &&     ln -s /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/mods-available/mongodb.ini /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/cli/conf.d/30-mongodb.ini ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 70fb0e84cadd
Step 79/183 : ARG INSTALL_AMQP=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b098b3255568
Step 80/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_AMQP} = true ]; then     apt-get install librabbitmq-dev -y &&     pecl -q install amqp &&     echo "extension=amqp.so" >> /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/mods-available/amqp.ini &&     ln -s /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/mods-available/amqp.ini /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/cli/conf.d/30-amqp.ini ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 04961c520591
Step 81/183 : ARG INSTALL_PHPREDIS=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4a2d00994bb3
Step 82/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_PHPREDIS} = true ]; then     printf "\n" | pecl -q install -o -f redis &&     echo "extension=redis.so" >> /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/mods-available/redis.ini &&     phpenmod redis ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f35c80ddfc2f
Step 83/183 : ARG INSTALL_SWOOLE=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5c779920b305
Step 84/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_SWOOLE} = true ]; then     if [ $(php -r "echoPHP_MAJOR_VERSION;") = "5" ]; then       pecl -q install swoole-2.0.11;     else       if [ $(php -r "echo PHP_MINOR_VERSION;") = "0" ]; then         pecl install swoole-2.2.0;       else         pecl install swoole;       fi     fi &&    echo "extension=swoole.so" >> /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/mods-available/swoole.ini &&     ln -s /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/mods-available/swoole.ini /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/cli/conf.d/20-swoole.ini ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 999e38c568b3
Step 85/183 : ARG INSTALL_LIBPNG=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0dad6265a73d
Step 86/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_LIBPNG} = true ]; then     apt-get update &&    apt-get install libpng16-16 ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5df6edbe19f6
Step 87/183 : ARG INSTALL_IONCUBE=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 20e8373f203d
Step 88/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_IONCUBE} = true ]; then     curl -L -o /tmp/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz https://downloads.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz     && tar zxpf /tmp/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz -C /tmp     && mv /tmp/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}.so $(php -r "echo ini_get('extension_dir');")/ioncube_loader.so     && echo "zend_extension=ioncube_loader.so" >> /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/mods-available/0ioncube.ini     && rm -rf /tmp/ioncube* ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ccffd15de80a
Step 89/183 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ed0648949997
Step 90/183 : ARG INSTALL_DRUPAL_CONSOLE=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f6940a191ac1
Step 91/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_DRUPAL_CONSOLE} = true ]; then     apt-get -y install mysql-client &&     curl https://drupalconsole.com/installer -L -o drupal.phar &&     mv drupal.phar /usr/local/bin/drupal &&     chmod +x /usr/local/bin/drupal ;fi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2c3b82d5112c
Step 92/183 : USER laradock
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0138351b7079
Step 93/183 : ARG NODE_VERSION=node
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4de9d56eadb2
Step 94/183 : ENV NODE_VERSION ${NODE_VERSION}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a3049ac24d54
Step 95/183 : ARG INSTALL_NODE=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a9646107f28c
Step 96/183 : ARG INSTALL_NPM_GULP=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bb463dc9b7c4
Step 97/183 : ARG INSTALL_NPM_BOWER=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e918f0c1a35c
Step 98/183 : ARG INSTALL_NPM_VUE_CLI=false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 36c77d3ad002
Step 99/183 : ARG NPM_REGISTRY
 ---> Using cache
 ---> aa05b14877da
Step 100/183 : ENV NPM_REGISTRY ${NPM_REGISTRY}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8368a192374a
Step 101/183 : ENV NVM_DIR /home/laradock/.nvm
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4debd2f7ff9a
Step 102/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_NODE} = true ]; then     mkdir -p $NVM_DIR &&    curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash         && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh         && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}        && nvm use ${NODE_VERSION}         && nvm alias ${NODE_VERSION}         &&if [ ${NPM_REGISTRY} ]; then         npm config set registry ${NPM_REGISTRY}        ;fi         && if [ ${INSTALL_NPM_GULP} = true ]; then         npm install-g gulp         ;fi         && if [ ${INSTALL_NPM_BOWER} = true ]; then        npm install -g bower         ;fi         && if [ ${INSTALL_NPM_VUE_CLI} = true ]; then         npm install -g @vue/cli         ;fi         && ln -s `npm bin --global` /home/laradock/.node-bin ;fi
 ---> Running in 86cd61a256fa
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12819  100 12819    0     0   9465      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  9467
=> Downloading nvm from git to '/home/laradock/.nvm'
=> Cloning into '/home/laradock/.nvm'...
=> Compressing and cleaning up git repository

=> Appending nvm source string to /home/laradock/.bashrc
=> Appending bash_completion source string to /home/laradock/.bashrc
=> Installing Node.js version node
Downloading and installing node v11.3.0...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v11.3.0/node-v11.3.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################## 100.0%
Computing checksum with sha256sum
Checksums matched!
Now using node v11.3.0 (npm v6.4.1)
Creating default alias: default -> node (-> v11.3.0)
=> Node.js version node has been successfully installed
=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
v11.3.0 is already installed.
Now using node v11.3.0 (npm v6.4.1)
Now using node v11.3.0 (npm v6.4.1)
node -> stable (-> v11.3.0) (default)
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
/home/laradock/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/bin/gulp -> /home/laradock/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
+ gulp@3.9.1
added 254 packages from 162 contributors in 89.45s
npm WARN deprecated hoek@5.0.4: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
/home/laradock/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/bin/vue -> /home/laradock/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js
```

Answer (score -2):

Desculpa mas não entendi o seu problema. No log apresentado não apresentou nenhuma falha, pelo contrario só obteve sucesso. Os WARNs apresentados foram pela versao desatualizada do npm que pode ser atualizado com o seguinte comando: npm@latest -g